# Refresh buffer after changing margin

Tags: centering

If I change margin and evaluate the code, it will only change only in the new window, but I  also want write it the have for the new buffer or even write it as a function.
How do I activate it also for my current buffer, after I change the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe code like this might help?

```lisp
(setq my-margin-left 10) ;; eval to change the left margin immediately.
(setq my-margin-right 5) ;; eval to change the right margin immediately.

(defun my-update-margins ()
  (set-window-margins (get-buffer-window) my-margin-left my-margin-right))

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'my-update-margins)
(add-hook 'window-state-change-hook 'my-update-margins)
```

Comment: that is awesome, thank you so much, what is the "add-hook" for?

Comment: These `add-hook` are only used as a trigger for the margin update function. In this case the margin is a fixed value, so it seems that only `window-state-change-hook` is enough, or maybe there is a more suitable hook. In my case I am changing the margin by percentage, so I needed these two hooks to detect `window-width` changes by window splitting or frame resizing.